# Daily email counter in python from outlook

Tags: python

I need some help with understanding how to use time ranges in this case.
What I am doing is: Using Python to count emails in a folder by day so I can make a "daily trend" with the data in Excel.
My problem is that I can do just

daytime_range = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(day)
(where day is a range number inserted by the user so lets say he inserts "7" then I want to display 7 days of daily count and eventually store it somewhere or just print the values)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is: how to select the time interval of 1 day going back x times since present time.

Comment: Please provide some more detail: How are you handling the data in python, i.e. are you using pandas, numpy arrays or something else? What does the code that you have so far look like (apart from the line that you included)?